# toggle / display image through an event listener

Tags: javascript

I have a list of featured products which I get through an API call, with the title and the icon displayed in the list. All the products also have images (which I also get through the same API call)

I want the image to not display when the icon is not active, but to display when the icon is active. Not sure how I get to display that specific image when the icon to that product is active.

(kinda new into coding, so sorry if this is a weird question)

```
export function featuredProducts(products)

const featuredProductsContainer = document.querySelector(".featured-products_list");

featuredProductsContainer.innerHTML = "";

for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  console.log(products[i]);
  if (products[i].featured) {
    featuredProductsContainer.innerHTML +=
      `<li class="featured-products">
<p>${products[i].title}<i class="far fa-flag" data-name="${products[i].title}"></i></p></li>
<img src="http://localhost:1337${products[i].image.url}" class="${products[i].title}" 
height="300" width="300" style="display: none;">`;
  }
}

const flag = document.querySelectorAll(".featured-products i");

flag.forEach(function(icon) {
  icon.addEventListener("click", clicked);
});

function clicked(event) {
  event.target.classList.toggle("fas"); //active
  event.target.classList.toggle("far"); //unactive
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR You'll want to add css to hide/show the images (As @barmar answered above).

I will propose a slightly different approach, which is toggling the classes on the images directly, to avoid a more complex rearrangement of the markup and gigantic css selectors.

But first, to make it easier, you should place the `img` tags inside their `li`, not beside them.

So, first, let's move the closing `li` tag to the end, after the `img`. Note I'm also removing the inline style of `style="display: none;"`.

```
for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  console.log(products[i]);
  if (products[i].featured) {
  featuredProductsContainer.innerHTML +=
      `<li class="featured-products">
<p>${products[i].title}<i class="far fa-flag" data-name="${products[i].title}"></i></p>
<img src="http://localhost:1337${products[i].image.url}" class="${products[i].title}" 
height="300" width="300"></li>`;
  }
}
```

Then, in your click handler, let's do something different:

```
function clicked(event) {
  // remove all active classes
  const $imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.fas')
  $imgs.forEach(i => i.classList.toggle('fas'))

  // add active class to targeting img
  const $img = event.target.closest('li.featured-products').querySelector('img')
  $img.classList.toggle("fas")
  $img.classList.toggle("far");
}
```

Lastly, modified from from @barmar

```
.featured-products img.fas {
  display: block;
}

.featured-products img.far {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS. Since your event listener toggles the `far` and `fas` classes, use CSS selectors that match an `img` inside those containers.

```
.featured-products.fas img {
  display: block;
}

.featured-products.far img {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to go about this, a lot depends on what triggers the active state of the icon.
if it's any kind of input and you can keep the data in the same container then all you need to do Is add an "active" css class to the parent. This is the most performant way as you keep reads, writes and any reflows to a minimum.
Just add a general rule in in your css for the active class:
`.active img { visibility: visible; }`

If the images are in a separate element, you can add a dataset custom property to the icon in your html. With a value you can use in Javascript.

I. e.

`<img id="icon" dataset-foo="imgContainer">`

and in JS

`var imgContainer = document.getElementById(icon.dataset.foo)`
`imgContainer.classList.add("active")`

You can wrap it in a function and maybe save any references in an object. This way it's easy to keep track of any data and have very readable code.